# Firebase database for survey results

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to store my survey results data in the firebase database. I have structured it as the following: `organization_id > survey_id > user_id > question_id : choice_id`

Example : `2:organization_id, 25: survey_id, 225: user_id, 101: question_id, 1/2/3/4/5: choice_id`

[firebase database structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S8m9O.png)

I want to show how many users selected a particular choice for a question. 
[Expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oRQuK.png)

1. How can i do that using firebase java-script API's ?
2. Is there any better ways to structure this data ?

Answer (score 1):

You are probably going to want another node that keeps the number of choices selected per question. Something like:

```
org_id > survey_id > question_id > totals > choice1: numberResponses
                                          > choice2: numberResponses
```

Its common to have to store the same data in a different format depending on how your application will use it.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'll try it and let you know.